# Struct empacotada?

Tags: c, struct

O que acontece quando coloco um atributo `packed` em uma `struct`?

Qual a diferença da `struct` que tem esse atributo?

```
struct test
{
        unsigned char  field1;
        unsigned short field2;
        unsigned long  field3;
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes : *specifies that each member [...] of the structure or union is placed to minimize the memory required.*; Não consigo descobrir uuma descrição desta funcionalidade para o compilador clang.

Comment: Normalmente os identificadores com dois *underscores* são especificos de determinado compilador. Se conseguires escrever os teus programas sem usares essas funcionalidades, tem mais garantias que esses programas sejam portáveis,